# v4l2loopback on Yocto

Tags: module, yocto, recipe, v4l2loopback

I'm begginer on Yocto and I try to add v4l2loopback to my image

I download current source on github (https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) and i try to compile with with recipe

```
SUMMARY = "V4L2Loopback"
DESCRIPTION = "v4l2loopback module"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"


# Use local tarball
SRC_URI = "file://v4l2loopback-master.tar.gz"

# Make sure our source directory (for the build) matches the directory structure in the tarball
S = "${WORKDIR}/v4l2loopback-master"

inherit module

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD = "v4l2loopback"
```

bitbake give me :

```
| NOTE: make -j 4 KERNEL_SRC=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work-shared/genericx86-64/kernel-source DEPMOD=echo MODLIB=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/v4l2loopbackd/1.0-r0/image/lib/modules/4.18.22-yocto-standard CC=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -fuse-ld=bfd -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/v4l2loopbackd/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/v4l2loopbackd/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/v4l2loopbackd/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/v4l2loopbackd/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work-shared/genericx86-64/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel LD=x86_64-poky-linux-ld.bfd  O=/media/yocto-irts/distro/build/tmp/work-shared/genericx86-64/kernel-build-artifacts modules_install
| make: *** No rule to make target 'modules_install'.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

I think i have to patch Makefile but i don't know how

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Why not pointing the SRC_URI to github itself?

Comment: I try on beginning. But as i said i'm beginner and i have already worked with archive .I take difficulties one by one ;)

Comment: To clarify, are you asking what changes to make to the Makefile, or how to create a patch to modify the Makefile?

Comment: @ThibaultBernard - did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile for v4l2loopback doesn't have a `modules_install` target.  However the `install` target will do what was intended.

You can substitute the target used for the module install step by adding this after `inherit module` in the recipe:

```
MODULES_INSTALL_TARGET = "install"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written an updated recipe for v0.12.7 of v4l2loopback. Since this is the first link that comes from Google I wanted to post it here if anyone happens to need it. However the module didn't seem to be compatible on my kernel form an SOC vendor.

```
DESCRIPTION = "A kernel module to create V4L2 loopback devices"
LICENSE = "GPL-2.0-only"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=b234ee4d69f5fce4486a80fdaf4a4263"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git;protocol=https;branch=main"

SRCREV = "1ecf810f0d687b647caa3050ae30cf51b5902afd"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit module

MODULES_INSTALL_TARGET = "install-all"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "KERNEL_DIR=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "PREFIX=${D}${prefix}"

DEPENDS += "help2man-native"

PACKAGES += "${PN}-utils"
FILES:${PN}-utils = "${bindir}/v4l2loopback-ctl"

RDEPENDS:${PN}-utils += " \
    gstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    sudo \
    v4l-utils \
    "
```